# How do I grant sql permission to an object in a different schema as dbo?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, privileges

This

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[test].[someTable] TO [MyUser] AS [dbo];
```

fails with error

`Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find the object 'someTable', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.`

If I remove the AS [dbo] part it works fine. Can someone explain why this is and the implication of removing the as dbo part?

This is for SQL Server 2012

Comment: Varies based on database  this looks to be MSFT: SQL Server but please add a tag indicating RDBMS and version.

Comment: @xQbert I didn't see a SQL2012 tag but added to OP

Comment: @user3953989 did you find the answer for your question?

Comment: @gofr1 I did thanks! Sorry I forgot to update this

Comment: I'm glad this helped you! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS with GRANT - Specifies a principal from which the principal executing this query derives its right to grant the permission (from MSDN).
So it means `[dbo]` dosn't have permission to GRANT something on `SCHEMA [test]`. I think you should run this before your query:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::[test] TO [dbo] WITH GRANT OPTION;
```